# How to create a 3D button in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

It is possible to design a button that it is looking like a 3D object (example below) in PyQt5?

[image: Example]

I have looked all around the web, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is a _3D button_?

Comment: No, Qt doesn't provide such effect "out of the box". Either provide create the images using an image editing program and then use style sheets, or subclass QPushButton and do the painting on your own.